# What's new for C++ and STL in VS2010 SP1?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

Just saw that VS2010 SP1 Beta is released. But the [release notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/12/09/vs2010-sp1-beta-what-s-on-it-for-c-developers.aspx) are a bit lacking in details.

Anyone know what kind of changes have been made to C++ and the STL?

I can't install it so I would appreciate if someone would like to share.

Comment: The post at 9 Dec 2010 9:02 PM adds quite a lot of meaty detail... I doubt there's much more to say.

Comment: did you read the comments in your link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is written that there is nothing new in language and library, only bugfixes.

Answer (score 0):

As Tony and Idan K points out the answer is in the comments (which I missed) in the link i posted.

[Answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/12/09/vs2010-sp1-beta-what-s-on-it-for-c-developers.aspx#10103019)